# How to download data In background in iOS?

Tags: ios, multithreading, background-process

I have one scenario. My requirement is like below..

When I click a button that time one service will call and after getting success response I have to call another service in background for content download in every 15 mins. If user close the application or kill the apps then it should be work. It should be call a service for download and download the data and save in document directory. This all process are working in background only.

Please anybody can help me. Is it possible or not, If possible how can go through this.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Use `NSURLSession` for it.

Docs:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013509-SW1

Example:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SimpleBackgroundTransfer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013416

You can check these tutorials:

http://www.appcoda.com/background-transfer-service-ios7/
http://www.raywenderlich.com/51127/nsurlsession-tutorial